# Is it possible to implement some semantic like this in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

So basically in `C` , we can implement some semantic like this:

```
int foo(int a )
{
    if (a == 100)
        return 0;
    else
      {}

    a = a + 1;
    foo(a);
}
```

So I am trying to use `Prolog` to implement the same semantic here, but what I am really confused is whether Prolog has some thing to represent 
        if (a == 100)
            return 0;
        else
          {}

Could anyone give me some help on this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is Prolog translation (I assume your mean `return foo(a);`, not just `foo(a);`):

```
foo(A, Result) :-
    ( A = 100 ->
        Result = 0
    ;
        NextA is A + 1,
        foo(NextA, Result)
    ).
```

It will run forever if A > 100, exactly like your C function.

Comment: The original function returns 0 for all inputs a <= 100.

Comment: @schrobe: consider using finite domain constraints instead of low-level arithmetic, so you can pose a query like `?- foo(A, 0).` without running into errors.

Comment: @schrobe: I think it's **undefined** for a<100 and **not terminating** for a>100. Actually, some compiler will complain ( and forbid compilation of that code ? ).

Answer (score -1):

Are you aware that this function always returns 0?

Anyway, here is a solution how you can do this in Prolog:

```
foo(100,0):-!.
foo(A, Result):-
    A1 is A+1,
    foo(A1, Result).
```

Comment: `?- foo(100,1).` should fail, but does not terminate.